# Join two objects into one, updating keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I join two arrays, updating the "qty" key without duplicating the "title" key?

Example:

obj1

```
obj1 = [{
    id: 0,
    qty: 1,
    title: "HEINEKEN0 350ML"
}]
```

obj2

```
obj2 = [
    {
        id: 0,
        qty: 5,
        title: "HEINEKEN0 350ML"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        qty: 1,
        title: "HEINEKEN0 600ML"
    }
];
```

Output I need:

```
output = [
    {
        id: 0,
        qty: 6,
        title: "HEINEKEN0 350ML"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        qty: 1,
        title: "HEINEKEN0 600ML"
    }
 ];
```

Comment: I presume `obj1` and `obj2` are actually arrays of objects, not singular objects as their name suggests?

Comment: That, of course, I was mistaken in the nomenclature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate both arrays together and use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the values for each title.

```js
const obj1 = [{
    id: 0,
    qty: 1,
    title: "HEINEKEN0 350ML"
}],
obj2 = [{
    id: 0,
    qty: 5,
    title: "HEINEKEN0 350ML"
},
{
    id: 1,
    qty: 1,
    title: "HEINEKEN0 600ML"
}];
const res = Object.values([...obj1, ...obj2].reduce((acc,{title,qty,id})=>{
  (acc[title] = acc[title] || {id,qty: 0,title}).qty += qty;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```